# return value after the class is terminated

Tags: java

Good day.

I am making a JPanel class which contains controls for the user to input.
The JPanel class will be called by the Parent class and it is inserted to a JDialog.

I figured that I can pass the value I wanted through setDialogData method so I can customize the texts of the labels. but here's the question. I have a save button inside that JPanel and I'm trying to figure out, How will I send the data over the the Parent class before the JDialog closes?

```
public class Dialog_Input extends javax.swing.JPanel {

public Dialog_Input() {
    initComponents(); //lets assume this has two buttons and a couple of controls..
}
public void setDialogData(String id, String name, String desc){
    lblDialog_ID.setText(id);
    lblDialog_Name.setText(name);
    lblDialog_Desc.setText(desc);
}
```

Comment: make a static field which is set when saved and retrieve this field then by simply calling it

Comment: so a static class from the parent will be accessed by the child? is that correct? maybe I should clarify the question even more.

Comment: Yes clarification would indeed be really helpful

Comment: the question has been updated. My apologies for not being able to express my question. English is not my first language.

Comment: Do you intend for this to be a modal window?

Comment: I have figured by adding a parameter to a constructor ex: `public SampleClass(String){..}` I was able to send data over. but is there a way to return one before the class is disposed?

Comment: What's wrong with adding a reference to your parent class in your JPanel so your button listener can call it and pass whatever is needed back?

Comment: @JornVernee yes I do.

Comment: @pvg Can you give a sample or reference? I've been studying java all by myself. we have not been thought of proper Parent-Child relation.

Comment: @pvg I have looked for reference to parent and It does work nicely. I think what I am looking for is something called Polymorphism since the panel will be a generic panel for dialogs.

Comment: Just add an instance variable to your `JPanel` subclass that holds a reference to the potential receiver of your data. When you get the data, call the receiver.

Comment: The method you call on the receiver is going to be polymorphically dispatched. You can make an interface specifically for the receiver, if you're going to have lots of them, for instance. To decouple this further, if you need to, you can make the JPanel subclass be a producer of events and have potential receivers of data register as listeners. Lots of options, kind of depends on the details of what you're doing

Comment: thanks! I'll hit the books with this one. I think this will come really handy in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should add a onClose listener - which sets the variables on close...
After that add some variables in  your parent class which will be set when the Dialog Closes, and setup some setters.
after that add a "Parent-class-object" variable into your child-class and add this object to the constructor
In the constructor set the class JPanel to the passed JPanel like this:

```
public class Dialog_Input extends javax.swing.JPanel {

private JFrame/*or other Object of parent Class*/ parentFrame; 

public Dialog_Input(JFrame parent) {
    parentFrame = parent;
    initComponents(); //lets assume this has two buttons and a couple of controls..
    //setup onCloseListener
}
public void setDialogData(String id, String name, String desc){
    lblDialog_ID.setText(id);
    lblDialog_Name.setText(name);
    lblDialog_Desc.setText(desc);
}

//method being called on close
private void onClose(){
    parentFrame.setA(settingA);
    parentFrame.setB(settingB);
    parentFrame.setC(settingC);
}
```

finally call the JPanel/Dialog with `this` as object to be passed

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, I'll study this even further.

Comment: Thats what Stackoverflow is for!